# sas one-liner

Tags: sas, command-line-arguments

Is there a way to run a one-liner in sas, or do I have to create a file?  I'm looking for something like the -e flag in perl.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My favourite is using the -stdio option

Either:

```
sas -stdio
```

Then start typing.  Or ...

```
echo "proc options; run;" | sas -stdio
```

Answer (score 5):

The Unix version of SAS was ported from MVS years ago and to make a long story short, the SAS executable does not import from STDIN.  To make this work in Unix, merely alter slightly the previous suggestion into something like:

```
echo "your SAS code" > temp;sas -sysin temp
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: There are further command line options to control where the output and log go.

Answer (score 3):

```
sas -initstmt '%put hello world ; endsas ;' 

sas -initstmt 'proc print data=sashelp.class; run ;'
```

Off course this could also be:

```
sas -initstmt '%inc large_program.sas; endsas;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Never having used sas, what I might try is something like:

```
echo <insert sas code here> | sas --execute-file -
```

Oftentimes applications will let you specify '-' as a file to have it read from STDIN. And 'echo' just prints its arguments out, and the | connects them together.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `-nodms` option. This will give you a command line version of Base.